# error build: Undefined symbol: _OBJC_CLASS_$_ADBMobile

Tags: xcode, adobe, ios16, xcode14

I'm trying to build my project which uses AdobeMobileSDK on XCode14 and seeing the compilation error "error build: Undefined symbol: *OBJC_CLASS*$_ADBMobile". However, the same works perfectly fine with XCode13

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seeing the exact same since Xcode 14

EDIT: Found a solution that worked for me, included -lAdobeMobile to your Other Linker Flags in Build Settings.